# Resource Failed To Load, streaming Mp3 playback with mediaelement.js

Tags: mediaelement.js

I'm working on a audio streaming app for reddit http://alienstream.com/ and for whatever reason my links randomly fail with "resource failed to load" mid track, I've been unable to find out the reason why, I double check the links and they're totally valid and download fine. I'm using mediafire to host my files and medialement.js for playback. Any idea why this might be happening?

Comment: Maybe [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/) or [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) would reveal the problem?

Comment: I'm thinking that the download is getting cancelled by the CDN, there doesn't seem to be any errors on the clientside code. I think it has to do with that mediaelement.js doesn't buffer the file entirely and CDN closes the connection. Is there a way to adjust how much gets buffered. I read through the documentation and didn't see any

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I switched to jplayer and I am still having the same issues

This seems to be a bug in chrome with streaming mp3 playback via html5 audio. It doesn't occur on firefox and if i fallback to flash it disappears, for now i've enbabled a "legacy option" and added the following line

error: function(e) {if(e.jPlayer.error.type=="e_url") {if(e.jPlayer.status!==undefined) {$("#player").jPlayer("play", e.jPlayer.status.currentTime)} else {next_track()}};}

This causes the song to stop for about a quarter of a second then resume in the exact spot it errored, obviously not ideal, but it's better than it was

Answer (score 1):

I found the following Here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jplayer/o-d0XIC1YKM

"Having conducted some research into this -- there appears to be a systemic bug in Chrome that causes the connection to drop (most obvious with larger files). This is reported in several places.
The fixes I have tried include the following:
1. Contact your host as ask if KEEP-ALIVE is set to the default ON or OFF -- you want it to be ON.
2. Insert the following code into your .htaccess file:

Header set Connection keep-alive

3. Set the "preload: auto" option as described below -- and also described in the API on the jplayer website. Yes -- overwrite 'metadata' with 'auto' on Line 248 of the jquery.jplayer.js file -- and upload!

I am still not getting 100% reliability with all of this -- but it does appear much improved."

Comment: Hi there, I don't suppose you've had any more successful results with this? Thanks.

Comment: I actually ended up switching to an embedded player, dropping the stream due to legal constraints. However; if a flash fallback was forced I had no issues, so i ended up switching to flash primary using an html5 fallback and the javascript hack posted below where i force playback of the currently playing track again on error.